# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function - why?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query like this and sometimes we got the errormessage: 
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I don't understand when and why?
I can see that the executionplan vary between different databases and different SQL-server versions and I have realized that different SQL-server versions do different choices for the order to run the query.

Is it only luck if the query runs ok or is there a good explanation?

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(5) = (SELECT descriptionname FROM Table1 WHERE   
nameCode = 'SpecificCode')

SELECT        Table2.TableID
             ,SUBSTRING(Name,1,(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1))-1) AS Name
             ,SUBSTRING(Name
            ,(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)
            ,((CHARINDEX(':',Name,(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)))-(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1))
                       ) AS Name2
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN TypeTable
ON Table2.ttID = TypeTable.ttID
WHERE Code = 'Test'
AND Name LIKE '%:%'
AND  @param = 'True'
```

If we try the query below it does work every time. What is the big and important difference?

```
SELECT                Table2.TableID AS [Id]
                     ,SUBSTRING(Name,1,(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1))-1) AS Name
                     ,SUBSTRING(Name
                     ,(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)
         ,((CHARINDEX(':',Name,  
(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)))-(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1))
                     ) AS Name2
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN TypeTable
ON Table2.ttID = TypeTable.ttID
WHERE Code = 'Test'
AND Name LIKE '%:%'
AND  (SELECT descriptionname FROM Table1 WHERE nameCode = 'SpecificCode')  
= 'True'
```

Comment: You're saying sometimes.. do you get different data each time it runs?

Comment: No, not different data. Only different result - error or not!

Comment: It's not luck. The query plan affects the performance of the query, not the correctness of the results. Something is up with your data; add some samples which can be used to reproduced the issue.

Comment: But the data don't fulfill the requirement to do the substring. Some data are only one character etc.

Comment: You're falling foul of the issue documented under [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). There's little sign that MS are ever going to fix it properly. (You'll see that my last comment on the issue pointed out that the error could be "anything" including a `SUBSTRING` with a negative length)

Comment: So you meanr that the code is ok but SQL servers bahavior is a little bit weird some time?

Comment: Yes. *Logically*, the `SELECT` clause should be processed after the `WHERE` clause and so those `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` calls should only be called on `name` values that are known (from the `WHERE` clause) to contain `:` characters. Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't always follow the logical processing order and, worse, it then produces errors that wouldn't have been produced if it had followed that order.

Comment: And, worse, your second query that runs correctly "every time" - unfortunately, it's also not *guaranteed* to run without issue. Just about anything may cause the server to generate a different execution plan in the future that again produces the error.

Answer (score 2):

In the face of a very brittle statement like

```
SUBSTRING(Name ,
       (CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1) ,
       ((CHARINDEX(':',Name,  
        (CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)))-(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1))
AS Name2
```

and the error *Invalid length parameter passed* I wouldn't start with looking at the engine.

Instead the problem is likely data related.

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748(v=sql.110).aspx) for the length parameter

> length
>
> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many
>   characters of the expression will be returned. **If length is negative,
>   an error is generated and the statement** is terminated. If the sum of
>   start and length is greater than the number of characters in
>   expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.

I would look for data that would cause an negative values for length and I'm sure you'll find your problem

e.g.

```
SELECT        
         Table2.TableID
         Name
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN TypeTable
ON Table2.ttID = TypeTable.ttID
WHERE Code = 'Test'
AND Name LIKE '%:%'
AND  @param = 'True'
and (CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)))-(CHARINDEX(':',Name,1)+1)) < 0
```

If you've eliminated this. Then yes you do have the [problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) that  @Damien_The_Unbelieve mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581329/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substring-function-why/35581920?noredirect=1#comment58850063_35581329r)

Initially I assumed that a CTE would do the trick however it seems the optimizer can overoptimize there as well. So as Damien [further explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581329/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substring-function-why/35581920?noredirect=1#comment58850869_35581920)

> the only thing I rely on is splitting the query into two distinct
>   queries and using a temporary table or table variable to store
>   intermediate results.

Comment: I've linked to a SQL Server connect issue below the question. Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't always follow the rules and it may be evaluating those expressions for `name` values that don't contain a `:`. Even though, *logically*, it should not be evaluating those expressions for such rows.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yikes! I guess filtering with a CTE first then applying the SUBSTRING is the thing to do

Comment: nope, the optimizer can see through CTEs and still push evaluations too far. There's some suggestion that putting pre-requisites into a `CASE` may prevent the optimizer going too far, but pretty well the only thing *I* rely on is splitting the query into two distinct queries and using a temporary table or table variable to store intermediate results. Which goes against most (usually good) advice of writing a single query and letting the server work out how best to do it.